# Plug-In Store doesn't have the option for adding / trying plugins (post upgrade 2.6 -> 3.5)

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugins

Having recently upgraded a dev instance of CraftCMS 2.6 to 3.5, I'm trying to add the plugins via the store.  I can find all the plug-ins I want to add, however there's no option on the page to add / try the plug-in.  I figure I've probably missed something basic.

Anyone got an idea of what I should be looking for here?

(am pretty new to this environment...)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in your `config/general.php`, you will probably find that you have `'allowUpdates' => false` set for the environment you are trying to trial the plugin on (stage/prod?).

Change that to `'allowUpdates' => true` and you will be able to install what you want.

Comment: Thanks - I'm accepting this as the answer - i also had in the config 'allowAutoUpdates' which I also had to set to true for this to work propoerly.  Thanks for the tip.